# Erase all [data]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) tag is ridiculously broad and someone even changed the description of it so people don't use it.

There was a [Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198275/burninate-the-data-tag) made for it but it was closed (not sure why it wasn't migrated to the Meta StackOverflow site).

Either way it should be burned. Let's vote?

Comment: It was closed because questions are not being migrated back here unless they are tots amazeballs awesome.

Comment: I agree that it is too broad.  But does more need to be done?  Besides nuking it, are there usages that should be made more specific (like [bigdata])?

Comment: At least a couple of [html][data] questions are about `data-foo` attributes, which may be worthy of their own tag.  Plenty more are just 'extract data from webpage' which are arguments in favor of burnination.

Comment: @pnuts I think you're right. Thanks for mentioning that. I removed the request for retagging.

Comment: Relevant: [Make it easier to prevent new questions being added in a tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Usage guide has:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! This tag is hopelessly broad and doesn't really tell us what the question is about. See `[here]http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256746/request-to-burninate-the-data-tag`.

The tag wiki has:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! This tag is hopelessly broad and doesn't really tell us what the question is about. See here.

[META](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198275/burninate-the-data-tag) has:

> [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) is way too broad and doesn't really give meaning to questions. It definitely doesn't sound like something you can be an expert on.
>
> Can / should it be burninated?

With net +14 for that Question.

At present this OP has +25 / -0.

Judging by the comments both here and there, the upvotes indicate agreement with burnination (though IMO that is not what they should, for meta questions other than those tagged [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)).  The comments are sparse but seem unanimous - [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) should ***go***.

There are at present no questions tagged *only* [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) but 12,713 [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) + one or more other tags. That number will keep increasing as long as [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) stays around and while manual removal is restricted to a few per person per day ("to avoid flooding the front page" and/or "too many notifications to users").

So far ***all*** the indications have been that [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) should be burninated - yet in two years it has not been. Even if it *will* never be cleaned up, it certainly *should be* - or at least the Usage guide and wiki rewritten to acknowledge that [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) remains valid.

Comment: Reminder: editors should **not** edit blatantly off-topic questions that happen to have this tag (thus spamming the front page with noise). Just flag/vote for closure.

Comment: Speaking of this, thanks for spamming the front page with your `microsoft` tag edits today.

Comment: My front page is filled with useless old questions right now, all re-activated by a horse shoe removing the [data] tag.  There are a lot of SO-users right now with a question that isn't going to get an answer because they are not visible.  Yeah, that's just too bad.