# Blacklist the [data] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

The [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) tag was [burninated once before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256746/erase-all-data). It was re-created yesterday and has since gained [27 new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data). Can we please burninate it again and blacklist it?

**March 8:** It took two weeks to finally burninate the tag. Questions kept getting re-added before the tag could be automatically removed. Can it be blacklisted now?

**April 4:** And it's back! This tag just won't die. Please blacklist it!

**May 23:** Back again!

**June 8:** And again!

Comment: It got 27 questions in one day?

Comment: I cleaned up those 27 posts again, stamping out the fastgrowing weed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so then… [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @StephenLeppik: No, because it's still not blacklisted, so there's nothing stopping it from coming back again.

Comment: I wonder how many of those were iOS or Swift questions, since [Swift 3 added associated types without the NS prefix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326078/2415822), so `NSData` is now just `Data`.

Comment: What are the options for people asking about data munging or, say, efficient data import issues?

Comment: [tag:data-import] and [tag:data-munging] both exist (not that either is a *great* tag)

Comment: @bright-star Mention data munging or data import in the text of the title and/or question? There doesn't need to be a tag for every concept you can possibly ask about.

Comment: @bright-star do we need a [tag:question] tag too?

Comment: Gah, and today another 4 questions with the tag have sprung up, meaning that it was recreated again by someone. Cleaned up once more, that may buy us another day.

Comment: And 4 more right now (for a moment)...

Comment: Another 6 questions today... This tag just won't die.

Comment: Another 22 mostly terrible questions have been added to the tag. Can we blacklist it already?

Comment: Do you remember who created it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters time for elevate the issue to cm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enough is enough, the tag has been blacklisted (thanks, Shog9)!

[image: K.O.!]

Comment: -1 you did not use a Sam Jackson meme when you started off with *Enough is enough* ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver: can't a ninja be creative and original? :-D

Comment: @NathanOliver: besides, I'm currently reading [this book](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2017/feb/12/norse-mythology-neil-gaiman-review-bloomsbury) out loud to my kids, it may have shaped my thinking.

Comment: That would do it.  Thank you to you and Shog for blacklisting.